# Joda betweenDays (LocalDate,LocalDate) not applicable

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, java-time

I am having trouble using Joda `daysBetween` function. It keeps telling me

```
The method daysBetween(ReadableInstant, ReadableInstant) in the type Days is not applicable for the arguments (LocalDate, LocalDate)
```

when I try to insert two `localdate` items.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(reviewDate, formatter);
        Date dateNow = new Date();
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(dateNow.toString(),formatter);
        int days = Days.daysBetween(date,date1).getDays();
```

I am trying to get the number of days between `reviewDate` and the current date `date1` what m I doing wrong?

Comment: Something must be totally wrong - maybe your imports. The expression `Days.daysBetween(LocalDate,LocalDate)` must be compilable!!! If not then I have the suspicion that you mix `java.time.LocalDate` with the Joda-class which has the same name (leaving different package aside).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You speak about Joda-Time-class `org.joda.time.LocalDate`. Of course, the expression `Days.daysBetween(ReadablePartial,ReadablePartial)` can [process such an input without problems](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween-org.joda.time.ReadablePartial-org.joda.time.ReadablePartial-), but you have a problem?! This has given me the idea that your imports might be wrong. And indeed:

You also use this expression:

[DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-)

**But that code is not Joda-code, it is Java-8-code**. So you obviously mix-up the different classes `org.joda.time.LocalDate` with `java.time.LocalDate`. And that is what your compiler is complaining about. Don't mix both libraries. They are not compatible, and the partially equal names will not help, too but can increase confusion.

**Solution:** Abandon Joda-Time completely since you are using Java-8. Instead of `Days.daysBetween(...)` you can use:

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date, date1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should convert `LocalDate` to `DateTime` using one of the following methods

```
LocalDate::toDateTimeAtCurrentTime()
LocalDate::toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()
LocalDate::toDateTime( LocalTime )
LocalDate::toDateTime( LocalTime , DateTimeZone )
```

Then you pass `DateTime` to a `daysBetween()` method.

Comment: See my comment on other answer. No conversion to `DateTime` is necessary.